# How can I disable sync-scrolling in Visual Studio Code during Live share?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-liveshare

I am sharing my project in Live share in Visual Studio Code and I have problem with scrolling. Everytime I scroll, other users see it. Is it possible to disable scrolling synchronization and work independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user settings (VS-Code), set `"explorer.autoReveal": false`. It is listed under "File Explorer" on the default settings side.